# What happens when you vote on a deleted question/answer?

Tags: support, voting, deleted-questions, deleted-answers

If I down-vote, or up-vote, a question or answer, and then it is subsequently deleted, does the vote still count towards the total vote count on my profile?

Or does it revert back to the original vote-count? If so, will I be re-awarded the 2 points that I lost if I had down-voted the question or answer?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are some rules around deleted questions/answers, which stem from [this Meta post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/7238/175248):

> Deleting and undeleting posts may affect reputation as well, if these posts have votes. Actions taken on deleted posts cease to affect reputation within five minutes, unless the post meets the following criteria (in which case the reputation affects will be permanent):
>
> - The post had a score of at least +3
> - The post has been visible on the site for at least 60 days

In effect, the vote count is impacted unless it falls under those criteria.