# Should I delete my tumbleweed questions that have gone negative after a ton of time?

Tags: discussion, specific-question

I don't think any of the other "Should I delete my question?" questions is applicable directly. Apparently I got some attention and two of these have been downvoted. The first I am going to delete since looking at it again I see it is way too broad (actually it is not negative, but it is not a good fit for SO IMO):

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44754367/django-server-with-heavy-data-model

The other though seems OK, but it is a tumbleweed, and just got down voted:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50084519/smoothen-zoom-motion

The questions is specific: **Should I delete the second question as well, even though it looks OK for the sole reason it is a tumbleweed that now got downvoted?**

**To clarify why I do not think this is a duplicate (specifically of what was marked, but any other similar question**

The question is regarding tumbleweeds, meaning questions that had a neutral score for **a very long time**, and thus are likely not interesting to nearly anyone. A negative vote on one of these after a long time deserve special attention (positive as well, but that would be different attention) could mean they fall a bit on the side of "not good/a good fit", but I wanted to see what were the thoughts of others on this.

Comment: You could try and make them a good fit as best as you can?

Comment: @Script47 The first I do not think can be salvaged. The second though seems OK, so I am unsure about it. I am really only asking this because these questions seemed to have garnered 0 interest (hence tumbleweed badge), but now after a long time have gotten negative attention. I would actually still like the second one answered.

Comment: You could always attach a bounty to the second one if you want more interest.

Comment: @Script47 Thanks, I am familiar with the solutions. I am really asking a specific question - do I delete the second question if it looks OK, but is a tumbleweed and has now gotten a downvote?

Comment: I made an edit to reflect this properly.

Comment: Would it be possible to show in an animated gif what you mean in that last question? I personally don't understand what a choppy cursor is or looks like. If there is a specific place where you think that choppy cursor is created/drawn/interfering place maybe a comment so it is clear where you're looking at to get fixed. As you say it depends on which image you use, maybe also provide an example that doesn't exhibit what you see? Maybe your code is fine, but the images you use are the problem. I don't think that last one needs to be deleted.

Comment: @rene I will try to add an animation later. Basically it seems like the cross-hair in the zoomed in portion seems to skip more than one pixel at a time, or reacts with a delay.

Comment: The first question reads to me as a design question and those tend to be broad and answers are at best only useful for you not for other future visitors. You might want to check the help of software engineering.se to see if your question would fly there. Or try their chat if you can.

Comment: @rene I agree about that.

Comment: @feelingunwelcome I tried to clarify why this is not a duplicate. I think a 0 score question receiving a negative (or positive for that matter) vote after a long time needs special consideration.

Comment: By the way, this happened again. I think someone is running a script to target these questions.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, you should not feel pressured to delete a question for the sole reason that it's a tumbleweed that got downvoted.

If you feel it's still useful and on-topic and you still want an answer, you're welcome to leave it around.

Although it's not particularly likely to get an answer at this stage, unless you draw attention to it in some way (like by improving it with an edit or adding a bounty). This Meta post might draw attention to it, but it may not be the kind of attention you want and it would be considered an abuse of the system to post on Meta specifically in an attempt to get an answer (there may be some language-specific chat rooms you can post to, but you'll need to look for those and see whether they allow that yourself).

And of course you may or may not want a negative-voted post associated with your account and delete it for that reason.

Answer (score 0):

Deleting questions just solidifies the down votes. That is it makes the votes permanent and irreversible, that is until you un-delete the question again, and they still count against your account in a behind the scenes way, [if you delete a lot of questions that also triggers penalties as well that are based on the down votes the deleted questions received.](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/281205/if-my-question-is-downvoted-do-i-have-to-delete-it-to-recover-my-reputation) Even if they no longer directly affect your rep. *[Do some research on this because the specific rules suibject to change.](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285016/what-happens-when-you-vote-on-a-deleted-question-answer)*

There is little benefit to deleting a question, unless it is so off-topic it is just going to get down voted to oblivion more because of the `meta-effect`.

Better to try and improve questions that are on-topic and hope you get some sympathy counter votes or retractions of the down votes even if you do not get an answer.

#### Personal Opinion:

The *Django server with heavy data model* question is just off-topic, it should be deleted.

The *Smoothen zoom motion* question is not half-bad, that means it is not half-good either.  I would delete it and try and improve it and un-delete it. This should not trigger any negative effects and keeps you from being hit with `the meta-effect` while you try and edit it. [A down vote is not the end of the world as it is only a `-2` to rep. A single up vote is `+5` so in this case it is pretty simple to improve it enough to net a gain.](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation)

Comment: First, thank you for the opinion. I tend to agree with you but I have little time to deal with that second question now days. I do not think this is a good answer though, since I am not really concerned about the down-vote (or a question ban to be honest. I do not think most of my questions were ever answered, and I do not ask that much), rather if tumbleweed-1 after a long time should be deleted as they may not be a good fit. Your opinion and the accepted answer I think answer this nicely.